# Flex 3 swf asset defined on css

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to define an swf on css. I don't want to load this swf using getStyle. I need something like this:

CSS

```
.loading
{
     source: Embed(source="/assets/loading_bar.swf");
}
```

MXML

```
<mx:SWFLoader styleName="loading" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
```

Is it possible? If its not possible with SWFLoader is there any other component that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling the loadStyleDeclarations() method of StyleManager class.

```
StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("../assets/loading_bar.swf");
```

Here's more information about it: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html